# Systematic criteria for selecting a new hard drive for servers

Tags: hard-drive

I'm required to come up with a specification for a new HDD to be purchased for a server I admin.

The current disk (purchased pre-installed in the system) already shows I/O errors (as evidenced by smartctl output), and thus I wish to follow an objective and systematic approach when deciding what HDD to purchase.

For background info about the server:

- my server is up 24/7
- server hosts both test and production apps
- hosts both database and web processes
- server has no redundancy peer - this is not a 1M+/s traffic node

What factors should I consider in choosing a hard drive for such a server?

Comment: Note: This question is **on topic** for Super User. It doesn't ask for a specific hardware recommendation, but instead for guidelines. See: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Are you sure that the current drive is installed in the CPU? My answer applies to regular systems without CPUS having built in storage.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, yes the drive was to be installed in the "tower" itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the disc(s) can:

1. Handle write and read loads at peek hours
2. Serve requests promptly without building up an excessive queue of requests
3. Get server-grade hard drives with a "high" mean time between error (5-year warranty drives)
4. Consider raid mirroring (affects point 1 and 2) or backups at regular intervals

   - production generally requires mirroring unless backup recovery can be done "fast enough"

Comment: meeting capacity needs and expected expansion of the service / application goes without saying...

Comment: Somehow, am operating within the limitation of just one HDD for the job. So I was trying to arrive at the best setup I could attain (within reasonable constraints).